# Javascript element translate and lifecycle

Tags: javascript, css

I'm doing an js assignment and the goals as mentioned in the fiddle below is to drag the main div, show when the div is centered and to translate it to it starting position.

**goals:**
After releasing ".draggable" it should animate back to its original position.

Currently I'm stuck with translating the div and understanding why the flow only works once then gets "frozen" and doesn't remove listeners.

I would love some clarifications on how should I approach the translate portion and can replicate this behavior as long as the client runs.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .draggable {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        cursor: grab;
      }

      .draggable-inner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
      }

      .draggable-inner.top {
        background: #1ADECB;
      }

      .draggable-inner.bottom {
        background: #1A8FDE;
      }

      .draggable.animate {
        transition: 500ms transform ease;
      }

      .markers {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      .marker {
        background: yellow;
        opacity: 0.2;
        transition: 500ms opacity ease;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .marker.visible {
        background: #1ADE91;
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .center-x-marker {
        width: 10px;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .center-y-marker {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="draggable">
      <div class="draggable-inner top"></div>
      <div class="draggable-inner bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="markers">
      <div class="marker center-x-marker"></div>
      <div class="marker center-y-marker"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      let isDragging = false;

      const deltaToCenter = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      const dragPosition = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      const screenCenterPosition = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };

      const draggable = document.querySelector('.draggable');
      const markerX = document.querySelector('.center-x-marker');
      const markerY = document.querySelector('.center-y-marker');

      let {
        width,
        height
      } = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();
      const draggableCenter = {
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2
      };

      draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag);

      function onTransitionEnd() {
        draggable.classList.remove('animate');
        hideMarkers();
      }

      function hideMarkers() {
        markerX.classList.remove('visible');
        markerY.classList.remove('visible');
      }

      function handleDrag(event) {
        isDragging = true;

        let pX = event.pageX;
        let pY = event.pageY;
        draggable.style.left = pX + "px";
        draggable.style.top = pY + "px";

        let dragObj = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        
        if (dragObj.top === 145 && dragObj.bottom === 295){
            markerX.classList.add('visible');
            markerY.classList.add('visible');
        }
      }

      function stopDrag() {
        isDragging = false;
        var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
          elemRect = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();

        draggable.classList.add('animate');
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleDrag);
        draggable.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', onTransitionEnd);
        draggable.addEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionEnd);
        draggable.style.transform = (`translate(0px, 0px)`);
      }

      function initDrag(event) {
        isDragging = true;
        dragPosition.x = event.pageX;
        dragPosition.y = event.pageY;

        screenCenterPosition.x = parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth / 2);
        screenCenterPosition.y = parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight / 2);

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleDrag);
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what's your assignment goal? I don't get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, rephrasing now

Answer (score 1):

You main problem is that you are trying to reset the top left with transform.

```
// use left and top:

draggable.style.left = pX + "px";
draggable.style.top = pY + "px";
  // reset:
draggable.style.left = 0 + "px";
draggable.style.top= 0 + "px";

// or use transform:

draggable.style.transform = "translate("+pX+"px, "+pY+"px)";
  // reset:
draggable.style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
```

Also I moved your event listeners out of your functions since you don't really need to remove them.

```js
let isDragging = false;

const deltaToCenter = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
const dragPosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
const screenCenterPosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

const draggable = document.querySelector('.draggable');
const markerX = document.querySelector('.center-x-marker');
const markerY = document.querySelector('.center-y-marker');

let {
  width,
  height
} = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();
const draggableCenter = {
  x: width / 2,
  y: height / 2
};

draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleDrag);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
draggable.addEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionEnd);

function initDrag(event) {
  isDragging = true;
  dragPosition.x = event.pageX;
  dragPosition.y = event.pageY;
  screenCenterPosition.x = parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth / 2);
  screenCenterPosition.y = parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight / 2);
}

function handleDrag(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    let pX = event.pageX;
    let pY = event.pageY;
    draggable.style.transform = 'translate('+pX+'px, '+pY+'px)';
    let dragObj = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (dragObj.top === 145 && dragObj.bottom === 295) {
      markerX.classList.add('visible');
      markerY.classList.add('visible');
    }
  }
}

function stopDrag() {
  isDragging = false;
  draggable.classList.add('animate');
  draggable.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
}

function onTransitionEnd() {
  draggable.classList.remove('animate');
  hideMarkers();
}

function hideMarkers() {
  markerX.classList.remove('visible');
  markerY.classList.remove('visible');
}

draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag);
draggable.addEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionEnd);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleDrag);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: grab;
}

.draggable-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.draggable-inner.top {
  background: #1ADECB;
}

.draggable-inner.bottom {
  background: #1A8FDE;
}

.draggable.animate {
  transition: 500ms transform ease;
}

.markers {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.marker {
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: 500ms opacity ease;
  position: absolute;
}

.marker.visible {
  background: #1ADE91;
  opacity: 1;
}

.center-x-marker {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.center-y-marker {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable">
  <div class="draggable-inner top"></div>
  <div class="draggable-inner bottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="markers">
  <div class="marker center-x-marker"></div>
  <div class="marker center-y-marker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot rafael! from what i'm understanding I missed the part when I needed to transform .draggable by the px I was dragging?